# How to set up TCP communication between two computers

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am trying to use the TCP protocol with the System.Net.Sockets library to have one computer send a string to the other. Here is part of my host code. Is the listener object supposed to be declared with the client IP address or the host IP address (like it is in the code below)?

```
IPAddress ipAddr = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0]; //Automatically retrieves IPAddress. 

int port = 135; //specify port number.
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddr, port);
```

Also, here is a piece of my client code. Which constructor do I use?

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
```

Comment: `TcpListener` has a constructor which requires only the PORT # -- have you tried that?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The link you provided said that this constructor is now obsolete. Does that mean that I can't use it?

Comment: A given machine CAN have multiple IP addresses, in which case it necessary to be more specific than just port #.

Comment: OBSOLETE - good catch...My apologies.

Comment: I did not try this source code myself, but here's a link to a simple C# TCP client server setup in a WinForm from GitHub: https://github.com/r3bel/tcpClientServer

Answer (score 1):

The listener object listens on the **host's** IP. The constructor takes it as an argument because you could have several IP's on the computer and it doesn't know which one you want to listen on.

As far as the client goes, you can pick whichever constructor you want. By using the parameterized constructors, you can connect right away, whereas the default requires a call to one of the overloads of `Connect`. It mostly depends on if you actually want to connect at instantiation time.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the overloads you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the parameterized constructor? I have many questions but to avoid bugging you, are there any resources for this?

Comment: @EvanL A parameterized constructor is just one you pass arguments to (so it has parameters, as opposed to the default, parameterless one). Not sure where to point you for more basic resources like that other than MSDN and google.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a TCP server sample code:

```
int port = 135; //specify port number.
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
// Start listening for client requests
listen.Start();
```

And then you can select to use polling method to create a simple sync TCP server.

The client (PowerShell):

```
$Address = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("<hostName>")
$Port = 135
$client = New-Object System.Net.Sorckets.TcpClient
$Client.Connect($Address, $Port)
```

Comment: He was actually mostly right (in the server code), the only difference in your code is that you bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of a specific interface, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, you're right. Specify IPAddress.Any for the local IP address, tcp server will listen to requests from all network interface, it maybe not Evan expect.